# How to Insert Data into Database by using For Loop?

Tags: android, android-database

I am Inserting Number of product data into database by using for loop ,flow is like first it generate invoice and it add invoice data into database and then it add product details data in productdetails table but when i insert invoice data it will insert properly but when I insert data in productdetails table it will add two same record which is last product .it skip first product and Add second and last product twice

for Loop of productdetails sestion

```
  `        for (int m = 0; m < orderDetailsList.size(); m++) {

        //  pname,unitname,quantityname,pricename,discountname;

        pname = orderDetailsList.get(m).getProductname2();
        Log.e("&&&&&&%%%Productname", pname);

        unitname = orderDetailsList.get(m).getProductunit2();
        Log.e("&&&&&&%%%price2", String.valueOf(unitname));

        quantityname = orderDetailsList.get(m).getProductquantity2();
        Log.e("&&&&&&%%%quantity2", String.valueOf(quantityname));

        discountname = orderDetailsList.get(m).getProductdiscount2();
        Log.e("&&&&&&%%%quantity2", String.valueOf(discountname));

        pricename = orderDetailsList.get(m).getProductquantity2();
        Log.e("&&&&&&%%%quantity2", String.valueOf(pricename));

        Productwisetotalname = orderDetailsList.get(m).getProductwisetotal2();
        Log.e("&&&&&&%%%quantity2", String.valueOf(Productwisetotalname));


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_ADDINVOICEDETAILS,
                new Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        try {
                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            Log.d("response2....", "" + response);

                            if (jsonObject.getString("message").equals("orderdetail added successfully")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "orderdetail added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d("response2....", "" + jsonObject.getString("message"));

                            } else if (jsonObject.getString("message").equals("Some error occurred please try again")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (jsonObject.getString("message").equals("It seems orderdetail is already Exist")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (jsonObject.getString("message").equals("Required fields are missing")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (jsonObject.getString("message").equals("Invalid Request")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("invoice_id", invoice_id);
                params.put("product_name", pname);
                params.put("quantity", quantityname);
                params.put("price", pricename);
                params.put("discount", discountname);
                params.put("totalamount", String.valueOf(Productwisetotalname));
                return params;
            }
        };


        RequestHandler.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
```

`

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL or SQL Server

Comment: @PraneetNadkar  MySQL